# Using Crystal Report in MVC(ASP.net) application...(Not using *.aspx file)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, report

Any good idea to use crystal report with MVC(ASP.net) application as a normal view like *.cshtml ,instead of *.aspx page.

Comment: It is not a group for suggestions.. Post if you face any issue in using crystal report or any technology so that you can get your problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...Thanks Raphael...So final solution is,
In MVC3 directly cannot  use ReportViewer Control from *.chtml page.Can use report in two ways

1. Create an pdf file on fly from your control class Or
2. Create a aspx page from where you can show your report using report viewer.

Sample application with crystal report and MVC3 ,can check this.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-Crystal-Report-in-bb0e6229

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to directly use reportviewer inside razor pages. Here you have a link that gives you 2 workaround

[Using Reportviewer Control, within a Razor view, in the MVC3 Framework](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8397f6c-ceee-4528-b3f3-4e0bd7b90ca4/using-reportviewer-control-within-a-razor-view-in-the-mvc3-framework?forum=vsreportcontrols)